# Run WordPress frontend and backend in different domains

Tags: urls, security, ssl, site-url

I want to run my WP frontend as `www.example.com` and my backend (i.e. wp-admin) as `user1.example.org`, is it possible?

The reason is I want to host lot of sites in a single server which has only 1 IP and I need SSL support for wp-admin (i.e. *.example.org)

Comment: Did you try to link the domain user1.example.org to /wp-admin folder?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do it the way you mean. There are ways to host multiple SSL websites on a single domain both with Apache and Nginx, and it's much easier to implement than your idea. Check out these tutorials:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04